# Composer private package issue

Tags: magento, packagist, composer-php

I have created a private composer package in packagist.com but when I use 
composer require command to fetch it. My package coming under vendor folder which is on root.

But I want it to be in app/code folder. Is there any parameter for composer.json where I can set app/code, so it will come under app/code/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. According to the composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4), if your project uses the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) specification for loading classes, then adding the snippet below to the `composer.json` file would work.

NB: You will need to change `ProjectNameSpace` to the base namespace for your project.

```
...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "ProjectNameSpace\\": "app/code"
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: I tried same but it still places packages in vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically. You can't composer will always place the code in vendor directory. The code is external and therefore can be updated only by composer. It must not be in app/code as only code you modify for the project should be in app/code.

If you wish to make a Magento project, you should have the fallowing files in the versioning tool.

- app/*
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- .htaccess
- index.php

The other files will be handled by composer.

But if you really need to do it, but I don't see any reason to do so, then  you could use a post-update & post-install script to move the code. But it's a very bad idea.